# Is there a way to create a custom experience button (or edit frame button) that opens a dropdown with additional experience editor buttons?

Tags: experience-editor, commands

I have a situation where a rendering could use a set of customization buttons that are all related. Rather than filling up the rendering's edit frame, I'd like to add a button that can expand into a dropdown similar to how the datasource menu expands to show additional commands.

[image: edit frame showing datasource dropdown]

Is there anything built in that would allow custom buttons to open submenus of buttons?

---

Alternatively, is there a component that can be used in a custom command to open a custom dropdown that contain buttons to trigger different commands?

---

<sub>**Note**: I'm aware I can add buttons to the datasource and more dropdown menus, however this would be inappropriate for the buttons that I'd like to add.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I found a clue but not an exact solution. I found that the this dropdowns are hardcoded in `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeControls.js`. The related code is the `renderDsSection`. This function is called in the `updateCommands`.

So in my opinion you can create your own function based on the `renderDsSection` and then call it in the `updateCommands`.

As you can see all these sections are hardcoded, because they have some logic inside (`renderWorkflowSection`, `renderMoreSection`, etc.).